# VerificationController unrecognized selector iOS 5.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios5, in-app-purchase

I just added In-App Purchasing to my iOS app and a few of my users are crashing out with

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf0a6f10
```

Obtained from BugSense, the memory location refers to the last line of this excerpt from Apple's VerificationController.m

```
- (BOOL)isTransactionAndItsReceiptValid:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    if (!(transaction && transaction.transactionReceipt && [transaction.transactionReceipt length] > 0))
    {
        // Transaction is not valid.
        return NO;
    }

    // Pull the purchase-info out of the transaction receipt, decode it, and save it for later so
    // it can be cross checked with the verifyReceipt.
    NSDictionary *receiptDict       = [self dictionaryFromPlistData:transaction.transactionReceipt];
    NSString *transactionPurchaseInfo = [receiptDict objectForKey:@"purchase-info"];
...
```

receiptDict is generated by this code (also included in VerificationController.m)

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromPlistData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *dictionaryParsed = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data
                                                                           options:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                            format:nil
                                                                             error:&error];
    if (!dictionaryParsed)
    {
        if (error)
        {
#warning Handle the error here.
        }
        return nil;
    }
    return dictionaryParsed;
}
```

which should return an NSDictionary or nil.

ARC is turned on. This problem seems to only occur with iOS 5.0.1 users. While I did make necessary changes to VerificationController.m, this part has been untouched. I can't seem to replicate the problem on my iPad running iOS 5.1.1, but users have said that it is persistent even after reinstalling the app. If anyone can see something simple that I'm not doing right, I'd appreciate it.

**EDIT** 
Follow up question. What does it mean when

```
- (BOOL)isTransactionAndItsReceiptValid:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction

transaction.transactionReceipt
```

only provides an NSString and is it safe to ignore?

Answer (score 1):

looks like to me

```
 propertyListWithData:data options:NSPropertyListImmutableformat:nil error:&error];
```

return a string not a dictionary but it doesnt seems logic. are you sure the problem come from this?

Comment: This makes the most sense to me - [that method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000942-SW5) is documented to return `id`, not `NSDictionary*`, so it's very possible that the plist in question contains only a string. @NewEndian: you might consider checking if `[dictionaryParsed isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]` after parsing it.

Comment: Ugh, I was hoping that my first question on SO wouldn't be so obvious. I assumed that property lists were always NSDictionary. I will post an edit with a follow up question.